# C# Доступ к строке из ресурса культуры

Tags: c#, локализация

В C# (windows forms) добавил новый язык к форме, изменил текст компонентов и т.д, создался файл ресурсов для языка который добавил, добавил свою строку в этот файл ресурсов, - changelang - Изменение языка вступит в силу после перезапуска приложения. Теперь мне надо чтобы если к примеру русский язык, то брать эту строку которая в файле ресурсов русского языка если английский, то из английского файла ресурсов. Но не могу даже банально прочитать строку. ResourceManager.GetString не находит и возвращает null

Comment: Думаю, было бы неплохо, если бы вы добавили в ваш вопрос немного подробностей, код, к примеру, какие-нибудь скрины. А то проблему описали, а того, из-за чего она может возникать, не видно